# Trigger anime.js animation when element enters viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to run an anime.js when an image or element enters the viewport, but i cant seem to get it working. Im trying it with waypoints.js

This is what I have so far, its the 'this' part im having troubles with i think.

```
$('img').waypoint(function() {
        var CSStransforms = anime({
          targets: this,
          translateX: 250,
          scale: 2,
          rotate: '1turn'
          });
            }, {
                offset: '100%'
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to target the elements with `this.element` instead, Here's a working example:

<kbd>[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/VXPaVX?editors=1111)</kbd>

Per your question, you would modify it to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').waypoint(function() {
        var CSStransforms = anime({
            targets: this.element,
            translateX: 250,
            scale: 2,
            rotate: '1turn'
        });
    }, {
            offset: '100%'
    });
});
```

Comment: ah ok thanks. Any ideas how I can target the parent of this.element ?

Comment: You can just initialize the `.waypoint` off of the parent. I've updated the pen, but basically change `$('img').waypoint(function() {` to `$('img').parent().waypoint(function() {`

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is im thinking about using it for a menu without the waypoints. So when a menu item is clicked (li) theres an animation on the menu (ul). Kind of like this :

Comment: $("li:has(ul)").click(function(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      //$(this).parent('ul').addClass('hide');
      //$("ul",this).addClass('show');

      var cssSelector = anime({
        targets: this.element.parent,
        translateX: 250
      });

      });

Comment: Actually I just dug through the `element` in the console and it looks like you can just target `this.element[parentElement]`: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/pLRbrR?editors=1111

Comment: Unfortunatly im getting this when i try, any ideas ? Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined

Comment: Sorry I just saw your response: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/XEpKEZ?editors=1111 - use `$(this).parent()[0]`

Comment: Sorry but is there also a way to select just the first set of menu items so i can fade them out and fade in the submenu. When I try, the submenu wont fade back in because its parent is faded out.

Comment: I had to step away from my computer for a little while but I can take a look when I get back. Mind sending me a codepen with your actual HTML markup?

Comment: Ok thanks, il try yes. Basically I dont think it likes the arrow in targets: '.primary-menu > ul li a',

Comment: The full HTML would be helpful, but is this kind of what you're going for?: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/XEpKEZ?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks, kind of yes. Apart from I would need the submenu title to change to 'back' when the submenu is visible. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the

`targets : this` to  `targets: this.element`